# Laptop docking station for home use with ThinkPad W500?

Tags: laptop, hardware-rec, thinkpad, docking-station

On my old personal laptop (Dell 5150), I have been using an [XBrand Universal Docking Stand](http://xbrandproducts.com/sp-bin/spirit?PRODUCT=67&PRODUCT_LAYOUT=detail_across4_down5&PAGE=67&CATALOG=5) for years with an external keyboard and mouse hooked up to it.  It works OK for Windows XP, giving me USB ports, ethernet and speaker out.  It also works great as a stand to raise up the screen to eye level.  Also, at work I used a Dell laptop with a docking station so I am spoiled.

For my next home computer, I am planning on getting a new [ThinkPad W500](http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/catalog.workflow:category.details?current-catalog-id=12F0696583E04D86B9B79B0FEC01C087&current-category-id=EC3A24B73CCE493BB1C514421A9BB0B7) with Vista 64 (and the free upgrade to Windows 7), and would like to continue to benefit from the docking station.  The XBrand website still mentions the "upcoming" Vista release, so I don't think the drivers will work with Windows 7.  If I want to spend around $200, the W500 has some [nice options](http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/systemconfig.runtime.workflow:GetMoreInfo?fCode=/merchandising/US/specialoffers/popups/help_me_decide/Popup_helpme_docksreps.html%7Cstatic&type=help) (USB Port Replicator, Port Replicator, Advanced Mini Dock).  I need the extra USB ports and like the ideas of the external DVI and VGA ports for when I want a second monitor.  Also, I wish there was an eSata port, but there is not.

**Question**: Does anybody have any other suggestions, or do I just buckle down and buy the Advanced Mini Dock?  Will that be my best bet for Windows 7 driver upgrades?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd put of buying any (windows) Laptop until windows 7 is out and supported on the machine you want.

Comment: Probably good general advice, but I can't wait until October with how slow my laptop is now.  Also, I feel confident in the ThinkPad W500 supporting Windows 7.

Comment: Not really related to your question as pretty much all drivers for the W500 work in Windows 7. I know because I have that laptop and run Windows 7 on it. The only thing not working is switching graphics cards without rebooting but they are working on a driver for that.

Answer (score 1):

Thinkpad advanced dock sucks on windows 7 64 bit, do not rush, no drivers, no support, ...etc.

it's an advice from an expert, thanks.